# C# Recursive Function with Optional Parameter

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, recursion, optional-parameters

I'm having issues with `optional parameters` on `recursive functions`

Here is a sample code:

```
private static void RecursiveFunction(int x, int optional = 0)
{
    if (x < 5)
        RecursiveFunction(x + 1, optional++);
}
```

When invoking the function:

```
RecursiveFunction(0);
```

I've got the following results (just calling this code `string.Format("{0} - {1}", x, optional)` in the immediate window):

```
"0 - 0"
"1 - 0"
"2 - 0"
"3 - 0"
"4 - 0"
```

Am I missing anything here? Thanks!

Comment: try `++optional` instead of `optional++`

Comment: I would do `optional + 1`. It is more clear and avoids (the useless unused) side-effects.

Comment: optional is local to every method call.

Comment: @sgar91: Thanks, it worked. Maybe you should have added it as answer, ot as comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change from:

```
RecursiveFunction(x + 1, optional++);
//                               ^^
```

To:

```
RecursiveFunction(x + 1, ++optional);
//                       ^^
```

The first one does the action then increments `optional`.
The second one does the action after it increments `optional`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
++ var
var ++
```

> The first form is a prefix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand after it has been incremented.
>
> The second form is a postfix increment operation. The result of the
>   operation is the value of the operand before it has been incremented.

Comment: @KaeL. It's cool mate, everyone does mistakes like this and almost everyone has questions on Stackoverflow that now he's embarrassed by. :) In couple of months you will be a C# ninja. :)

Comment: Answer accepted! (Need to wait for the time interval to end before accepting) Thanks a lot! Can't find it on `Google` with the keywords I have, I resorted to ask here. :D

Answer (score 3):

You first called `RecursiveFunction` and then increased `optional`. You need to increase it first.

```
private static void RecursiveFunction(int x, int optional = 0)
{
    if (x < 5)
        RecursiveFunction(x + 1, ++optional);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to Increment before calling

```
RecursiveFunction(x + 1, ++optional);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `++optional` instead of `optional++` in your method call.

by using `optional++` you will not get the incremented value to be passed as parameter to the function, instead `0` will be passed to each function call. Your call should be:

```
RecursiveFunction(x + 1, ++optional);
```

Answer (score 1):

yes,

You need to do `++optional` instead of `optional++`